# How to deal with Different Shapes of X_train and X_test after OneHotEncoding?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-engineering, one-hot-encoding, binary-classification

I am trying to perform OneHotEncoding as well as feature scaling on my training and testing data separately, steps I did:

```
X = df.drop("target", axis = 1)
y = df.target

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

categorial_features = [List of Categorical Features]
numerical_features = [List of Numerical Features]

one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
scaler = StandardScaler()
tranformer = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot", one_hot, categorial_features),("standard_scaler", scaler, numerical_features)], remainder = "passthrough")

transformed_X_train = tranformer.fit_transform(X_train)
transformed_X_test = tranformer.fit_transform(X_test)
```

But now the shapes of `transformed_X_train`, and `transformed_X_test` are different, I know the reason why it is different, but I want to know how to deal with this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The issue that you are running into is because you are using the `fit_transform` method on both your training and test dataset. The correct way of using a transformer is to use `fit_transform` only on the training dataset so that it learns the parameters and applies the transformation, and then use `transform` on your test set to apply those learned parameters to transform your data.

Comment: Hi can you show me the code example to do the same for the scenario I have mentioned in the question, that would be really really helpful, I am new to ML. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what code example you need, but it is as simply as changing the second `fit_transform` call to `transform` to you only transform your test dataset.

Comment: One changing fit_transform to transform it is still causing the same shape disparity error.

Comment: Which one are you changing? You have to change the second one from `fit_transform` to `transform`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple way to do label encoding.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Year': 2020, 'Airport':2000, 'Casino':5000, 'Stadium':9000, 'Size':'Small'}, 
       {'Year': 2019, 'Airport':3000, 'Casino':4000, 'Stadium':12000, 'Size':'Medium'},
       {'Year': 2018, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':9000, 'Stadium':10000, 'Size':'Medium'},
       {'Year': 2017, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':10000, 'Stadium':15000, 'Size':'Large'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df = df.set_index(['Year'])
df

df_fin = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].astype('category').cat.codes for col in df}, index=df.index)
df_fin
```

[image]

Now, you can set your X & Y, get training samples and do testing, and basically do whatever you need to do!